# Import Angular Resizer in TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript, github

I am trying to integrate the following  [angular directive](https://github.com/Reklino/angular-resizable) into my AngularJS project (TypeScript + HTML components + `Angular 9.1.12`). However, I am unable to import the module into my app. I am trying `import { angularResizable } from 'angular-resizable';` in my `app.module.ts` file, but I am unable to use the `resizable` directive in my `component.html`. Any suggestions on how integrate this repository would be appreciated.

Comment: As I see from the package sources - this is a purely JS project without typings. Normally popular projects have also packages like `@types/<package-name>` for TypeScript support. Here this is not the case. I'd search for an alternative for Angular 2+.

Comment: Do you know of any angular 2+ alternative for creating a horizontal and vertical resize bar within a div?

Comment: simple googling gave this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-resizable-element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Angular 9, you aren't using AngularJS.

This package might be something you're interested in, as it's for Angular 4+
https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-resize-element